# I am trying this simple sudoku

Tags: java, duplicates, element

> I am trying a simple sudoku program. i started by taking the values in a 3D 
>       array and then copied them into a 1D array by using mr.serpardum's method. 
>       i know that there is an error at the point where i am trying to find
>       duplicate elements,because even if i give same numbers as input the output 
>       says "its a sudoku" but i can't to find it...apparently i can't add any 
>       image coz i dont have enough credits

```
    public class SecondAssignment {
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
    boolean result = false;
    int arr1[][];
    arr1 = new int[3][3];
    int arr2[];
    arr2 = new int[9];
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.println("Enter the elements in the sudoku block");
    //getting elements into array
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            arr1[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        }
    }
    //printing it in matrix form
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            System.out.print(arr1[i][j] + "\t");
        }
        System.out.println(" ");
    }
    //copying array1 elements into array 2
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) { 
        for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            arr2[i * 3 + j] = arr1[i][j];
        }
    }

    //finding duplicate elements
    for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
        for (int m = i + 1; m < arr2.length; m++) {
            if (arr2[i] == (arr2[m])) {
                System.out.println("Not a sudoku");
                //result = true;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Its a sudoku");
                //result = false;
            }
          }
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: First off, your current sudoku check is definitely wrong. The commented out one is closer, but not quite there. What you should do is set a `boolean isSudoku` to true, and then if you find a duplicate in your nested `for`'s `if`, set it to `false`. The reason you're having this logic error is because you're setting the boolean with each check, no matter true or false.

Comment: ya after looking at my output i knew that i was setting it with each check, i tried to correct it but it didnt quite work out and i was back to square one...but hey you are right,i tried your solution, and it worked...Thanx a lot :) :) :)

Answer (score 0):

You can update your code to following

```
//finding duplicate elements
for( i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++){
 for(int m = i+1; m < arr2.length; m++){
    if(arr2[i] == (arr2[m])){ 
      result = true;
      break;
    }
 }
}  
if(result){
System.out.println("\nNot a sudoku");
}
else{
System.out.println("\nIts a sudoku");
}
```

You should have used break as soon as the match was found.
This code just checks if duplicate element is present in the array (of size 9) or not.

Comment: Yes Sir!!!!..i tried your method and also @MarksAtomic  method..and they both work.although i think you both suggested the same thing...but anyway..thanks a lot... :) :) :) :)